# Increase memory for shared memory

Tags: macos, memory, operating-system, shared-memory

When trying to get shared memory, `shmget()` often fails because being unable to allocate memory. The physical size of RAM really shouldn't be the problem (4GB is enough, I think). 
Rather there's probably anywhere in the systems properties a limit for allocating shared memory set. Does anyone know, where I can find this property?

I'm using Mac OS X Version 10.6

Comment: When you have 4gb ram, isn't 1gb used to index that 4gb?  Or am I wrong about the ratios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the OS. [PostgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/kernel-resources.html) has tips for changing the shared memory limit on various platforms.

Comment: Thanks. The documentation provided what I needed. I just always forget to say what OS I'm using. I'll edit the question.